# Link in Label BlackBerry 10

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

I am using JSON to receive data and place it into List. There is a Label displaying the text that I am receiving from the JSON. In some of the cases there is a Link in the text. By default you can't click on the Link from the label. Is there a way to make the Link to be clickable?

```
Label {
       text:  "Click here to open browser and get redirected to www.stackoverflow.com";
       }
```

The output is "Click here to open browser and get redirected to www.stackoverflow.com" but the Link to StackOverflow is not clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TextArea instead of Label and set property editable to false, it would look same as Label.
Don't forget to set inputMode to either Text or Chat.

```
TextArea {
        text: "http://www.google.com"
        editable: false
        inputMode: TextAreaInputMode.Text
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use HTML in the label itself to style the text as a link, according to the [Text Styles documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/ui/text/styles.html).  You need to be aware of a few quirks though if you are going to apply any of your own styles, as discussed on the Blackberry Developer support forums [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/HTML-in-Labels-A-Notice-and-Warning/td-p/2121549).  The example below should work, using the default style which will colour the link blue, with bold and underline:

```qml
Label {
    text: "<html>Click here to open browser and get redirected to <a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>www.stackoverflow.com</a></html>"
}
```

Note: you may need to set `multiline: true` on the `Label` in order to see all of the text, depending on your layout.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign Text.RichText value to "textFormat" property of the Label:

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
  width: 360
  height: 360
  Text {
    text: "Click <a href=\"http://google.com\">here</a>"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    textFormat: Text.RichText
    onLinkActivated: {
      Qt.openUrlExternally(link)
    }
  }
}
```